# SFTP Can't upload module despite using owner's credentials

Tags: 7, files

I'm new to both Linux and Drupal, but I can see that the owner and group assigned to the drupal modules directory is one of my SU accounts on the server. When I log on to SFTP I use that same credential.

I tried to upload a module using Aptana studio and it tells me it can't create folders.

Do you feel that there's additional ownership info needed on the server side? Would my folder rights not be applicable when connecting via SFTP?

Answer (score 2):

Using `ssh` you can log in to the system to check about directory permissions using the same credentials you use with `sftp`.

try..

```
ssh user@host
```

to login and then use a number of commands to check permissions

```
ls -l                      //Lists files with permissions for user, group and other
chmod 755 dir/file         //Change file/directory permission
chown user:group dir/file  //Change the user/group ownership of file(s)
```

`scp` command can also upload file from local (*nix) machine to server.

```
scp path/to/local/file user@host:/path/on/server
```

Comment: Shoaib, thank you. I had already done the chown but not the chmod so I went up a folder and did a chmod on the drupal modules directory. It does not seem to have affected the ability to remote mkdir from within the sftp client I am currently using however, I will look into it further and comment on this thread when completed.